# Find all integral values of a, b such that the given equations have integral roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Find all possible integral values of a and b such that
$x^3+ax+b=0$ and
$x^3+bx+a=0$
have integral roots.

So I took the roots of the first equation as $\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1$ and the roots of the second equation as $\alpha_2, \beta_2, \gamma_2$.
Now,
$$\sum_{cyclic} \alpha_1 = \sum_{cyclic} \alpha_2 = 0$$
$$\alpha_1\beta_1\gamma_1 = -b, \alpha_2\beta_2\gamma_2 = -a $$
$$\sum_{cyclic} \alpha_1\beta_1 = a, \sum_{cyclic} \alpha_2\beta_2 = b$$

So I did some algebraic manipulations and got
$$\sum_{cyclic}\alpha_1^2 = -2a$$
So $a\leq 0$ and by symmetry $b\leq0$. But I found the if any one of the roots is $0$ then $a=b=0$.
So ignoring that case and assuming all roots are non zero I can deduce that exactly $2$ of $\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1$ are negative. Similarly for the second set of roots.

But I can't get past this.

Comment: The friend who gave me this problem told me that a=b=0 is the only solution but he doesn't remember how he proved it.